# Animating the addition of more polygons (Python: Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, polygon, matplotlib-animation

I am trying using python matplotlib to draw a honeycomb animation where each hexagon is added gradually (in a spiral manner outwards, add 1 hexagon at every refresh (e.g. 200ms)). I have previously used matplotlib animation before and I know how to animate/translate a single patch by using the `set_xy()` of a patch, and then returning that particular patch from the animate function.

But in this particular project, I am trying to create a NEW patch/hexagon every single time from within the animate function, which gets me stuck. As you can see from my current code below, for now I am just using a primitive method to add a new 'layer' of hexagons and repeated it for 3 times. It doesn't do the animation I intended, and it adds by an entire layer of hexagons instead of just 1 hexagon.

If someone could guide me **how to add more polygons/patches instead of just translating a single patch, in each animation frame**  I'll be happy to continue on my quest of coding it correctly.

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.path as mpltPath
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon as poly
import numpy as np
import time

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.xlim(-5, 5)
plt.ylim(-5, 5)
class Hex():
  registry = []
  radius = 0.5
  dist_apart = radius * np.cos(np.radians(30))*1.1
  def __init__(self, center):
    global ax
    self.idx = len(self.__class__.registry)
    self.center = center
    self.vertices = self.__class__.create_vertices(self.center)
    self.__class__.registry.append(self)
    ax.add_patch(poly(self.vertices, fill = False))
    
  @classmethod
  def check_is_occupied(cls, center):
    path = mpltPath.Path(cls.create_vertices(center))
    for each_hex in cls.registry:
      if path.contains_point(each_hex.center):
        return True
    else:
      return False      
  
  @classmethod
  def create_vertices(cls, center):
    return np.transpose(np.array([cls.radius*(np.cos(np.radians(np.linspace(0, 300, 6))))+center[0], cls.radius*(np.sin(np.radians(np.linspace(0, 300, 6))))+center[1]]))

  def fill_surround(self):
    for pos in range(6):
      new_center = [self.center[0] + self.__class__.dist_apart*2*np.sin(np.radians(60*(pos%6))), self.center[1] + self.__class__.dist_apart*2*np.cos(np.radians(60*(pos%6)))]
       if not self.__class__.check_is_occupied(new_center):
         Hex(new_center)

 a = Hex([0,0])

lister = list(Hex.registry)
for each in lister:
  each.fill_surround()

lister = list(Hex.registry)
for each in lister:
  each.fill_surround()

lister = list(Hex.registry)
for each in lister:
  each.fill_surround()

plt.show()
```